# Почему при вводе данных/аргументов 1 аргумент повторяется 2 раза и выдает ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с ошибкой, которую не могу исправить самостоятельно. Мне необходимо вывести в обратном порядке имена учеников. Первоначально подается число, сколько людей в группе. Потом подается список учеников

Мой код

```py
n = int(input())

r = {}

for i in range(n + 1):
    k = list(input().split())
    r[k[0]] = k[1]
    key_list = list(r.keys())
    val_list = list(r.values())
    j = list(set(val_list) - set(key_list))[0]
    print(j)
    for i in range(n - 2):
        j = key_list[val_list.index(j)]
        print(*(set(r.keys()) - set(r.values())))
        print(j)
```

Однако, если написать допустим John и через пробел Mariya, то выйдет что-то подобное

```py
------------ Начало ввода ------------
5
John Mariya
------------ Ввод окончен! -------------
Mariya
John
John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    j = key_list[val_list.index(j)]
ValueError: 'John' is not in list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы если я мог ввести вначале 5 (людей), и потом допустим

```
Petr Mariya
Ivan Liza
Mariya Ivan
Igor Petr
```

он мне выдал

```
Liza
Ivan
Mariya
Petr
Igor
```

Являюсь **как таковым новичком**, поэтому могу что либо недопонимать. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!
[image: P.S Полное описание входа/выхода]

Comment: А можно задание целиком? Формат ввода, что должно быть на выходе. А то из вашего кода абсолютно не понятно чего вы хотите им достичь.

Comment: Все исправлено!

Comment: Скорее всего первый цикл должен заканчиваться после присвоения r. Дальше надо убрать лишние табуляции во всех строках, начиная со строки key_list = ... Сейчас это всё получается в теле первого цикла, а это явно неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо разделить циклы ввода и циклы обработки (не всегда, но в вашем случае надо, т.к. для работы нужны полные данные).

```
n = int(input())

# обратный словарь: где ключ - имя студента, а значение - имя следующего студента
next_student = {}
for _ in range(n-1):
    name, name_before = list(input().split())
    next_student[name_before] = name

# находим студента который не является следующим ни у кого - он первый
name = (set(next_student.keys()) - set(next_student.values())).pop()
# цикл пока у студента есть следующий студент
while name in next_student:
    print(name)               # печатаем имя
    name = next_student[name] # переходим к следующему студенту
print(name) # печатаем имя последнего студента
```

Ввод:

```
5
E D
B A
D C
C B
```

Вывод:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```